# Remove word that only 3 character or less with PHP

Tags: php

i use a php class to make tag cloud from article, but i want to remove words that only 3 character or less, also remove numeric words.

example tags: 1111 monkey deer cat pig buffalo

i want result : monkey deer buffalo

PHP code from that class (full code [here](http://code.google.com/p/web-information-systems/source/browse/trunk/SentimentAnalysisProject/Sukalp/cloud.php?r=36))

```
    function keywords_extract($text)
{
    $text = strtolower($text);
    $text = strip_tags($text);

    /* 
     * Handle common words first because they have punctuation and we need to remove them
     * before removing punctuation.
     */
    $commonWords = "'tis,'twas,a,able,about,across,after,ain't,all,almost,also,am,among,an,and,any,are,aren't," .
        "as,at,be,because,been,but,by,can,can't,cannot,could,could've,couldn't,dear,did,didn't,do,does,doesn't," .
        "don't,either,else,ever,every,for,from,get,got,had,has,hasn't,have,he,he'd,he'll,he's,her,hers,him,his," .
        "how,how'd,how'll,how's,however,i,i'd,i'll,i'm,i've,if,in,into,is,isn't,it,it's,its,just,least,let,like," .
        "likely,may,me,might,might've,mightn't,most,must,must've,mustn't,my,neither,no,nor,not,o'clock,of,off," .
        "often,on,only,or,other,our,own,rather,said,say,says,shan't,she,she'd,she'll,she's,should,should've," .
        "shouldn't,since,so,some,than,that,that'll,that's,the,their,them,then,there,there's,these,they,they'd," .
        "they'll,they're,they've,this,tis,to,too,twas,us,wants,was,wasn't,we,we'd,we'll,we're,were,weren't,what," .
        "what'd,what's,when,when,when'd,when'll,when's,where,where'd,where'll,where's,which,while,who,who'd," .
        "who'll,who's,whom,why,why'd,why'll,why's,will,with,won't,would,would've,wouldn't,yet,you,you'd,you'll," .

    $commonWords = strtolower($commonWords);
    $commonWords = explode(",", $commonWords);
    foreach($commonWords as $commonWord) 
    {
        $text = $this->str_replace_word($commonWord, "", $text);  
    }

    /* remove punctuation and newlines */
    /*
     * Changed to handle international characters
     */
    if ($this->m_bUTF8)
        $text = preg_replace('/[^\p{L}0-9\s]|\n|\r/u',' ',$text);
    else
        $text = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]|\n|\r/',' ',$text);

    /* remove extra spaces created */
    $text = preg_replace('/ +/',' ',$text);
    $text = trim($text);
    $words = explode(" ", $text);
    foreach ($words as $value) 
    {
        $temp = trim($value);
        if (is_numeric($temp))
            continue;
        $keywords[] = trim($temp);
    }
    return $keywords;
}
```

I've tried various ways, such as use `if (strlen($words)<3 && is_numeric($words)==true)`, but it did not work.

please help me

Comment: ...`is_numeric($words)==true`) is wonky. It should be `if(strlen($words)<3 && is_numeric($words))`. More precisely you should perform the numeric check first, if you were to check like this `if(is_numeric($words) && strlen($words)<3)`.

Comment: @Lion: But even the former one should work. [The Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) says it returns true or false only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will slightly modify your process to make it run faster (I believe it should).

**Step 1:** Instead of replace each common word to empty string in `$text` (replace process is expensive), I will store each common words into hash table for later filter.

```
$commonWords = explode(",", $commonWords);
foreach($commonWords as $commonWord)
    $hashWord[$commonWord] = $commonWord;
```

**Step 2:** Filter common word, numeric and words that contain less than 4 digits at the same time.

```
$words = preg_split("/[\s\n\r]/", $text);
foreach ($words as $value) 
{
    // Skip it is common word
    if (isset($hashWord[$value])) continue;
    // Skip if it is numeric
    if (is_numeric($value)) continue;
    // Skip if word contains less than 4 digits
    if (strlen($value) < 4) continue;

    $keywords[] = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s].+/', '', $value);
}
```

---

The following is a full source code for this function (in case you want to copy and paste)

```
function keywords_extract($text) {
    $text = strtolower($text);
    $text = strip_tags($text);

    $commonWords = "'tis,'twas,a,able,about,across,after,ain't,all,almost,also,am,among,an,and,any,are,aren't," .
        "as,at,be,because,been,but,by,can,can't,cannot,could,could've,couldn't,dear,did,didn't,do,does,doesn't," .
        "don't,either,else,ever,every,for,from,get,got,had,has,hasn't,have,he,he'd,he'll,he's,her,hers,him,his," .
        "how,how'd,how'll,how's,however,i,i'd,i'll,i'm,i've,if,in,into,is,isn't,it,it's,its,just,least,let,like," .
        "likely,may,me,might,might've,mightn't,most,must,must've,mustn't,my,neither,no,nor,not,o'clock,of,off," .
        "often,on,only,or,other,our,own,rather,said,say,says,shan't,she,she'd,she'll,she's,should,should've," .
        "shouldn't,since,so,some,than,that,that'll,that's,the,their,them,then,there,there's,these,they,they'd," .
        "they'll,they're,they've,this,tis,to,too,twas,us,wants,was,wasn't,we,we'd,we'll,we're,were,weren't,what," .
        "what'd,what's,when,when,when'd,when'll,when's,where,where'd,where'll,where's,which,while,who,who'd," .
        "who'll,who's,whom,why,why'd,why'll,why's,will,with,won't,would,would've,wouldn't,yet,you,you'd,you'll,";

    $commonWords = explode(",", $commonWords);
    foreach($commonWords as $commonWord)
        $hashWord[$commonWord] = $commonWord;

    $words = preg_split("/[\s\n\r]/", $text);
    foreach ($words as $value) 
    {
        // Skip it is common word
        if (isset($hashWord[$value])) continue;
        // Skip if it is numeric
        if (is_numeric($value)) continue;
        // Skip if word contains less than 4 digits
        if (strlen($value) < 4) continue;

        $keywords[] = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s].+/', '', $value);
    }
    return $keywords;
}
```

---

**Demo**: ideone.com/obG6n

Comment: when i run my page, it become blank (error), but when i add { and } between `$hashWord[$commonWord] = $commonWord;` it show error `Warning: preg_replace()...` and `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

Answer (score 1):

You should change the `&&` to `||`:

from:
`if (strlen($words)<3 && is_numeric($words)==true)`

to:
`if (strlen($words)<3 || is_numeric($words)==true)`

and if you want to remove words that **have** 3 character or less, 
then you should use `<=` instead of `<`:
`if (strlen($words) <= 3 || is_numeric($words)==true)`

Comment: How? It must be `&&` rather than `||`. The varible `$words` must be numeric **as well as** its length must be less than or equal to 3. (**not** either of them but both of them at the same time should be satisfied).

Comment: @Lion he said: "I want to remove words that only 3 character or less, also remove numeric words." Also, checkout his example!

Answer (score 1):

you can do it with regex

change:

```
/* remove extra spaces created */
$text = preg_replace('/ +/',' ',$text);
$text = trim($text);
$words = explode(" ", $text);
```

to:

```
/* remove extra spaces created */
$words = preg_replace('/\b\w{1,3}\s|[0-9]/gi','',$text);
return $words;
```

and remove the following foreach section including return;

Here is the explanation of the regex pattern:

```
\b = Match a word boundary position (whitespace or the beginning/end of the string).
\w = Match any word character (alphanumeric & underscore).
{1,3} = Matches 1 to 3 of the preceeding token.
\s = Match any whitespace character (spaces, tabs, line breaks).
| = or.
[0-9] = Match any numeric character.
```

And here is the human understandable explanation of this pattern:
"Find a word that --has any word character from starting position to the length of 1 or 3 characters and a following white space-- or --any numeric character-- and replace it with an empty string.

Comment: now i use `$text = preg_replace('!\\b\\w{1,3}\\b!', ' ', $text); ` it's work for me :)

Answer (score 0):

```
If((strlen($word) <=  3) && is_numeric($words)){
     //Don't add in the list
}
```

Answer (score 0):

now i add `$text = preg_replace('!\\b\\w{1,3}\\b!', ' ', $text);`

before

```
    $text = preg_replace('/ +/',' ',$text);
    $text = trim($text);
    $words = explode(" ", $text);
```

no error :)

[source](http://forums.devshed.com/php-development-5/help-with-preg-replace-34726.html)

if you want use this php classes, you can get code [here](http://code.google.com/p/web-information-systems/source/browse/trunk/SentimentAnalysisProject/Sukalp/cloud.php?r=36)

thank you for all :)